# uninitialized constant CarrierWave::MiniMagic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minimagick

I'm trying to upload an image via AJAX, but, the controller doesn't respond.

Error: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::MiniMagic.

Here is my code:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImagesUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagic # << Error

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  process convert: 'png'

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [171,180]
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  #version :thumb do
  #  process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  #end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

and the trace:

> app/uploaders/images_uploader.rb:8:in `<class:ImagesUploader>'
>   app/uploaders/images_uploader.rb:3:in`'
>   app/models/image.rb:2:in `<class:Image>' app/models/image.rb:1:in`
>   ' app/controllers/events_controller.rb:28:in `edit'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
```

You missed a 'k' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have forgot to mount the image up loader. Hope this link will help you

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads